# Can you grind sexually in Islam with your spouse?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, knowing-islam

Can you grind sexually in Islam when you are married (grinding is when you rub your genital with your spouses buttocks or the private part)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is permissible, as long as the woman is not menstruating.